# backbone.js can't pass model item from collection's view to item's view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I want to pass model's todo item from  TodoListView from to TodoView. But it can't. My code  is like this.

```
    define(["jquery","underscore","backbone","todo_view","todo"],
function($,_,Backbone,TodoView,Todo){
    var TodoListview =  Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "ul",
    initialize:function(){
    _.templateSettings.interpolate = /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g;
    _.bindAll(this,"addTodo","render");
    this.collection.bind("add",this.addTodo,this);
                       this.collection.bind("reset",this.render,this);

                    },
    render:function(){
      this.$el.empty();
      this.collection.each(this.addTodo);
      return this;
      },
    addTodo:function(item){
      console.log(item.get("title"));
      // it's works correctly -> Backbone.model
      var todoView = new TodoView({model:item});
      var str = todoView.render().$el;
      this.$el.append(str);
      }
    });
    return TodoListview;
    });


// todo_view.js
define(["backbone","underscore"],function(Backbone,_){
    var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
            tagName: "li",
            template: "#todo-view-template",
            events: {
                "click .done": "toggleDone"
            },
            initialize:function(){
                _.templateSettings.interpolate = /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g;
                this.render();
            },
            render:function(){
                var str = $(this.template).html();
                var template = _.template(str,{name: "hello"});
                            console.log(this.model) //#-> Backbone.Model.
                            console.log(this.model.get("title")
                             //#-> undefined get method. why??
                return this;
            },
            toggleDone:function(){
            }
    });


    return TodoView;
});
```

I don't understand why this.model.get("title") method in TodoView outputs undefined. Do you have any idea? Thanks advance.

Comment: Why are you rendering `TodoView` twice? Once in `TodoView.initialize` and once in `TodoListview.addTodo`. You can remove it from `initialize` method.

Comment: How are you instantiating the `TodoListView`?  It might help to see that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you get if you inspect the model's attributes?

```
console.log(this.model.attributes)
```

Does it have the "title" attribute?

Additionally you might want to bind the context for render(). In initialize:

```
initialize:function(){
   _.templateSettings.interpolate = /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g;
     _.bindAll(this, 'render');
            this.render();
   },
```

Answer (score 0):

My collection has set  item to undefined  at 0 idx. So, it cause error.

I solved by this code...

```
if (typeof this.model !== undefined){
 this.model.get("title");
 }
```

Thanks for all.